# AngularJS: proper interaction between, separation of directives, controllers, templates

Tags: angularjs

I've been trying to work my way through the Angular Way of doing things and I'm currently trying to make sense of the proper use of directives and how they relate to the overall ecosystem of the app. At the moment, I'm trying to handle the basic logic of a form with distinct, editable elements and cancel/save buttons that commit or revert the state of the form.

Here's what I have, which is working. I'm using Slim templates and CoffeeScript so I'm going to try to clean it up into plain HTML and JS as I go, so please assume that any app-breaking syntactical errors are the result of mistyping for this post.

```
# excerpt of the template

<div my-form ng-repeat="band in bands">
  <div class="band-name">
    {{band.name}}
  </div>

  <div class="edit-band" ng-click="editBand(band)">
    Click to edit
  </div>

  <div ng-if="editingBand != band">
    {{band.tagline}}
  </div>

  <div ng-if="editingBand == band">
    <form class="form-horizontal" ng-submit="updateBand(band)">
      <input type="text" ng-model="band.tagline" />
      <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" />
    </form>
  </div>

  <div ng-if="uncommitedChanges">
    <button ng-click="saveChanges()">Save</button>
    <button ng-click="cancelChanges()">Cancel</button
  </div>
</div>


---------------excerpt of controller

# during init
$scope.bands = bands;
$scope.originalBands = angular.copy(bands);
$scope.uncommittedChanges = false

$scope.editBand = function(band) {
  $scope.editingBand = band;
}

$scope.updateBand = function(band) {
  $scope.editingBand = null;
  $scope.uncommittedChanges = true;
}

$scope.cancelChanges = function(){
  $scope.bands = angular.copy($scope.originalBands);
  $scope.uncommittedChanges = false
}

$scope.saveChanges = function(){
  $scope.uncommittedChanges = true;
  // bands are sent to the service that performs the update against the API
}
```

So, again, this all works, but is it an appropriately AngularJS Way of doing things? I get this feeling that a lot of that logic should be separated into a directive because it will be more reusable but I'm a little unclear of how to start that. For that matter, I'm not even positive that my hunch is right. Guidance would really be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this ended up being neither super complicated nor too wide to answer simply. It may not be the best way to do it but it's a start. Suggestions are welcome!

I noticed while reading a few blogs that you're able to define a controller that is responsible for your directive. Knowing this, the solution to the question, "How do I move my functions out of the controller and into the directive?" can be answered with, "You don't, you move them into a controller dedicated to your directive."

In the template, I call it like this:

```
<div id="show-bands" class="col-md-8" bands-form bands="bands"></div>
```

My directive is still pretty simple.

```
myApp.directive 'bandsForm', () ->
  return {
    scope: {
      bands: '=bands'
    }
    templateUrl: 'directives/bands/band_form.html'
    controller: 'BandFormCtrl'
  }
```

I create isolate scope with `scope: { bands: '=bands' }`, which means that whatever model I set the `bands` attribute equal to when calling the directive will be passed into the directive. This would be the equivalent of `<%= render 'templates/my_template', bands: @bands %>` in a Rails ERB template.

Finally, `BandFormCtrl` is a new controller dedicated to this directive. It contains everything that was in the shared controller prior to this refactor. As long as `bands` is defined and able to be passed down, everything works.

Comment: directive logic should be in directive, not in BandFormController. Main aim of directives - be reusable. It means be independent of controllers and views (only have services as possible dependencies).

Comment: This is reusable because it is all isolated. This controller is not shared by anything, it is only invoked by this directive, and its scope is provided by the directive. Whether it lives in a separate file or within the directive declaration itself doesn't matter.

Comment: Using a controller dedicated to a directive seems to be pretty common but if you have any resources that explain an alternative or why not to do this, I'm happy to read them. I haven't find any.

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly how things work in AngularJS :)
If you see you can encapsulate some code into directive to reuse it - do it. But I don't think anybody, except you, can say what you can reuse in code from that example :)  Maybe you want to put code which is inside ng-repeat into directive.

P.S.: `ng-if` is powerful directive and have differences in work with `ng-show`, I recommend you to read about it.

Comment: Great! But HOW do I move this behavior into a directive? All of the options regarding scope and declaring variables within the directive are a little overwhelming. I should probably isolate scope, declare `bands` at the beginning, but... then what? And how?

Comment: too wide question and answered many times already in a lot of tutorials and books. I recommend ng-book. Or you can find something other here: https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning

Comment: I don't mean to sound rude but is it really? There isn't a way to say, "These functions defined in the controller could look like this if implemented in a directive; moving logic from the controller to a directive in this case looks like this," or something like that? I'd know how to do that if someone asked this question for Ruby or Rails when describing logic shared between templates, controllers, models, modules, etc,... That can't be expressed with Angular?

Comment: it will give you nothing if I will write code instead of you.